# Jenkins pipeline check if choice parameter has bee nset/exists

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

At the beginning of my pipeline a choice is made:

```
  parameters {
    choice(
      name: 'jobRunMode',
      choices: ['Create/Update','Delete'],
      description: 'Job run mode')    

  }
```

However, when this build is triggered for the first time the user does not make a choice, thus this variable does not exist or is empty.

How do I check if this parameter exists or not?

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward conditional for object value assignment would be: `params.jobRunMode == null`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of checking, just add Default Value to this param so it always exists xD.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).